# how to abort a thread (running a form in it) without crashing the app?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have created a splash screen form for my wpf application. I am trying to show the splash screen while the main form is being loaded. I have created a thread in main form's constructor which shows the splash screen and this thread is aborted when the main form is fully loaded. **The problem is that the SplashThread.Abort() crashes my application.** So, is there some thing wrong in my approach for the splash screen or in my coding. I want to show the splash screen only for the time taken by the main form to be loaded.
Following is my piece of code.

```
private Thread splashThread;
 public App()
        {
            splashThread = (new Thread(() => (new BDTSplashscreen()).ShowDialog()));
            splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            splashThread.Start();

            this.Loaded += App_Loaded;
            this.Closing += App_Closing;
            try
            { 
             //My Stuff
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }


 private void App_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            splashThread.Abort();
            this.Activate();
        }
```

Comment: 1) don't make new threads to run forms. 2) You should never abort threads, there is almost no reason user code should ever be doing it. You should consider why you feel this new thread needs it's own form, if it is because your splash locks up without it you should go about fixing that lockup in the loading code, not making the splash it's own thread.

Comment: FYI, if your splash screen is simple and only contains an image, there is a special "Splash Screen" item template built in to Visual Studio.  It has a special build action, and it's designed to load as quickly as possible--before the WPF assemblies are loaded, JIT compiled, etc.  It also hides itself automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i did it:

- create a new view with this xaml and code behind:

  ```
  <Grid>
     <Label x:Name="ProgressMessage" Background="LightSteelBlue" Height="28" Margin="19,0,17,15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
         Foreground="White" ></Label>

  </Grid>

  public partial class Splash : Window
  {
      public Splash()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      async public Task ReceiveMessageAsync(string message)
      {
          await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
          {
              ProgressMessage.Content = message;
          });
      }

      public void ReceiveMessage(string message)
      {
          ProgressMessage.Content = message;

      }
  }
  ```
- then in your main method you call it:

  ```
  splash = new Splash();
  splash.Show();
  ```
- do your task and use the Receive message function to show the progress of your loading tasks:

  ```
  splash.ReceiveMessage("I'm Loading !!");
  ```
- then, when your loading task are completed you just close it using:

  ```
  splash.Close();
  ```

and launch your MainWindow.

Just a couple of notes:

your main method should of course be set as Start method for your application.
Your main method should also be wrapped by this:

```
Thread app = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
            });
            app.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            app.Start();
```

Comment: Pretty much simple and easy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This solution may not be appropriate for you, but it might help others.

If your splash screen is simple, i.e., only an image without any dynamic text, then the easiest implementation is to add the image to your project and change the **Build Action** to **SplashScreen** in the 'Properties' pane.

This will create a very lightweight splash screen that starts when you launch your application.  It uses unmanaged Win32, so it will display sooner than a WPF-based splash screen, which must wait for several assemblies to load and some code to JIT.

When your main window is shown, the splash screen will automatically be hidden with a nice fade-out effect.  It's fast and easy.

You might even be able to combine this simple splash screen with a more advanced one.  Show the simple one first, and then launch your own with the same size, position, and background image.  As the simple one fades out, it should look like the extra content is fading in.  See @mm8's answer for how to handle the threading.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `OnStartup` method of your `App.xaml.cs`, show the splash screen on a background thread, keep a reference to the splash screen window and then simply close it once the main window has been loaded. Something like this:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Window tempWindow = null;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
            new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

        tempWindow = new BDTSplashscreen();
        tempWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        tempWindow.Closed += (ss, ee) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
        tempWindow.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    }));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();

    //show the main window
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    mw.Loaded += (ss, ee) => tempWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => tempWindow.Close());
    mw.Show();
}
```

Comment: I would add an event to wait for, and wait untill the window is created in the thread,

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: Why would you wait to close the splash screen until the main window is closed? This makes no sense. It's closed when the main window has been loaded in the above sample code.

Comment: No, lets say, Are you really sure that the window (on the thread) is created before the  mw.Loaded is called? I think it should contain something like a synchronization.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: I see your point. However, in this case I guess that it actually takes a while to load the main window. Othwerwise it would be pretty pointless to display a splash screen on a background thread.

Comment: I think this is a great solution. Added a point. This way the splash screen will be painted even when the mailthread is busy.

Comment: He should evaluate it again... I would implement it the same way. _(although I would add the ManualResetEvent ;-) )_